# how to get the json data from the url in jquery?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, getjson

How to get the json array from the URL.I declare the mydata as a variable.**how to get the json array into the mydata?** using the following ajax

```
var mydata;
$.ajax({
 url: someurl,
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function() {

  }
});
```

Comment: Common, you almost got this yourself! :p

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski: Even I first thought he meant *extract parameters from query-string* when I first read it. But, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mydata;
$.ajax({
   url: someurl,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
      mydata = data; 
      console.log(mydata);
   }
});
```

alternatively you could use [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:-

    ***$.ajax({
     url: someurl,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(mydata) {
foreach(var data in mydata){
//do something.....    
}
      },
failure: function()
{
//error message
}
    });***
```